# How do I solve for the order of integration in the Fourier transform-based Differintegral?

Tags: complex-analysis, fractional-calculus

In a comment response to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1101432/imaginary-order-derivative) post someone brought up the Fourier transform-based Differintegral, which is defined as follows: $$f^{(s)}(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{- i \omega x}(-i \omega)^s \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t)e^{i\omega t}dt \, d\omega$$
How can I solve for $s$ (which is the order of differentegration) based on this definition?

Comment: What do you mean "solve for $s$"? What you have there is a definition, solving for $s$ should only yield $s=s$, a true statement, as you've defined it as such.

Comment: If everything makes sense then $f^{(s)}(x) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}[(i\omega)^s \mathcal{F}[f](\omega)](x)$ (if $f\in L^1$, $s \in\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathcal{F}[f](\omega)$ decreases fast enough when $|\omega| \to \infty$, then everything makes sense)