# Imaginary order differential equations

Tags: complex-analysis, fractional-calculus

I would like to find the solution of the imaginary order differential equation $y^{(2i)}+y^{(i)}+y=0$

I started with the Fourier transform differintegral as it seemed more suitable than the Riemann-Liouville fractional derivative,  as I saw on this post:
([Imaginary-Order Derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1101432/imaginary-order-derivative#)):
$$f^{(s)}(x)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{- i \omega x}(-i \omega)^s \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t)e^{i\omega t}dt \, d\omega.$$
Then I applied it to the equation,  including $y(x)=y^{(0)}(x)$:
$$f^{(s)}(x)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi} \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i\omega(t-x)}y(t)(-i\omega)^{s}dtd\omega,$$
and got to
$$\dfrac{1}{2\pi} \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i\omega(t-x)}y(t)(-i\omega)^{2i}dtd\omega + \dfrac{1}{2\pi} \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i\omega(t-x)}y(t)(-i\omega)^{i}dtd\omega +\dfrac{1}{2\pi} \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i\omega(t-x)}y(t)(-i\omega)^{0}dtd\omega$$

$$\dfrac{1}{2\pi} \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i\omega(t-x)}y(t)((-i\omega)^{2i}+(-i\omega)^{i}+(-i\omega)^{0})dtd\omega=0.$$

taking the derivative of both sides doesn't help to get any solutions besides $y=0$.

Any help would be appreciated.